# Keras multi input one shared embedding layer

Tags: keras, embedding

Is it possible to simply share one embedding layer with one input with multiple features ?
Is it possible to avoid to create multiple inputs layers one by feature.

I would like to avoid to create 34 input layers (one by feature).

The goal is to pass throw one embedding layer 34 feature sequence, get 34 embedded vector sequences. Concatenate them to obtain one super feature vector sequence. And then feed a LSTM.

input shape (None,100,34) -> Embedding_layer_size_64 -> (None,100, 34*64) -> LSTM -> softmax

hope it's clear

Answer (score 1):

The Solution:

```
# Shared embedding
embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size+1, output_dim = emb_dim, input_length = nb_timesteps, mask_zero = True)

# For every features we have it's own input
feature_inputs = [Input(shape=(nb_timesteps, ), name='feature_' + str(i + 1)) for i in range(nb_features)]

# Repeat this for every feature
feature_embeddings = [embedding_layer(f) for f in feature_inputs]

# Concatenate the embedding outputs
concatenated_embeddings = concatenate(feature_embeddings, axis=-1)

lstm_1 = LSTM(output_dim)(concatenated_embeddings)

output_layer = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(lstm_1)

model = Model(inputs=feature_inputs, outputs=output_layer, name="Multi_feature_Embedding_LSTM")
```